# How do I console log each of the arguments I pass into this test function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7XRjD/2/).

I'm trying to output `a`, `b`, and `c` consecutively. But `console.log()` is just giving me back the first value.

```
function test(values){ 
    console.log(values);
} 

test('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
console.log( arguments );
```

Keep in mind though that `arguments`, while looking like an array, is actually an object. You can convert it to an array, if needed, like this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Alternately, as [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex) pointed out in the comments, with jQuery you can simply do:

```
$.makeArray(arguments)
```

Comment: And since the question was tagged `jquery`, you can also use `$.makeArray(arguments)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7XRjD/4/)

```
function test(values) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}

test('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(a,b,c){ 
    console.log(a,b,c);
} 

test('a', 'b', 'c');
```

You are creating a function so arguments to that function should be match when you are calling this function. So if you want three parameters, then just add three parameters to your function.

Comment: It's possible to simply use the `arguments` object to access an arbitrary number of arguments passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a function which only accepts a single argument that is `values`. If you want to pass `a`, `b`, and `c`, change your function to accept three values:

```
function test(val1, val2, val3){
    console.log(val1 + val2 + val3);
}
```

or store `a`, `b`, and `c` on an array. In your code, the number of arguments don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript variable arguments

```
function blah() {
   console.log(arguments);
}

blah(1, 2); // [1, 2]
blah([1, 2], [3]); // [[1,2], [3]]
blah(1, [2, 3], "string"); // [1, [2, 3], "string"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has only one parameter and you are giving it three parameters. This won't work like an array - you have to modify the code:

```
function test(values){ 
    for( var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    alert(values[i]);
} 

test(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Comment: There is no reason to modify the code as you have above. The `arguments` object will allow for the retrieval of an arbitrary number of arguments passed to the function.

Comment: ok, that is a method, I agree with it , why downvote for another method which is working

Comment: I originally downvoted because I believed this to be a convoluted approach to the question at hand. Certainly not to make "make my answer correct". No offense was intended.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about other people's downvoting behaviour and don't nag for a reason when downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to use

```
function a( b, c, d){
 console.log(arguments);
}
```

`a(5, 8, 9, 9, 9)` will output

```
[5, 8, 9, 9, 9]
```

BTW, take a loot at other functions except of console.log()

- console.log(  myvar, "Logged!");
- console.info( myvar, "Logged!");
- console.warn( myvar, "Logged!"); console.debug(myvar, "Logged!");
- console.error(myvar, "Logged!");